# Does Best Buy/Best Sell locator work with satellites?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I have read conflicting reports. I tried this once but it only looked like the program was giving me the current sector best buys/sells. Do they have to be advanced vs normal satellites?

Using XRM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place Advanced Satellite in sector it has additional commands in menu `Advanced`: `Best Buy`, `Best Sell`. You can use this commands to list best buys/sells without need to visit that sector.

There is mod called [Universal Best Buys/Sells Locator](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=223503). It should be compatible with Albion Prelude.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there would be some sort of consolidation in the one panel across all sectors, but I suppose that is asking for a bit much.

Comment: I think, there are some mods for this, but did not find any yet. I will update answer when find one.

Comment: If you have Best Buys on your own ship, you can hit 6 on the menu for a Navigation satellite and get the best buys. I have started flying around in a ship with one of every ware on board so I can see the price for anything by using the navigation satellites and hitting 5.